# How to share local PC com port to vps?

Tags: windows, networking, serial-port

I have created an application that use a usb gsm modem. I want to try to run my application in my vps and connect it with the gsm modem in my local PC. My questions is:
- How to share local PC com port to vps?
- My local pc has a public (static) ip address. Is it necessary to have a public ip?
My local PC are using Windows7, and my vps are using Windows server 2012 r2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. At my local computer, I use hub4com as the server to share the com port with TCP connection. And at my vps I use com0com and hub4com. I use com0com to create a virtual com port, and hub4com to connect to hub4com (server) at my local computer.

When we create a virtual com port with com0com, it automatically create 2 virtual com port, for example: CNCA0 and CNCB0. As far as I know, CNCA0 is to be used by my application and CNCB0 is used by hub4com to connect to hub4com server (my local pc).
But, when I try to use that virtual com port (CNCA0) with my application I got an error. My program are created with c#, and I use SerialPort class and I think it only accept port name with alias COM only. Then I try to change the settings of CNCA0 (at com0com) by checking the "use Port class" options and "emulate baud rate" options. And the name are changed from CNCA0 to COM5 (it may be vary). And when I check the device manager, COM5 are appearing at "Ports (COM & LPT)"
section. And then I just run the hub4com and use CNCB0 to connect to the hub4com server in my local pc. I have test it and I can send an AT command from my application (use COM5 port) in vps to my modem at local pc.

The complete explanation can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/DraTeots/e0c669608466470baa6c).